# returning equation with all possible parenthesis combinations and the result of each

Tags: javascript, algorithm

On a recent interview, I was asked to return all possible combinations of order of operations on an input string, and the result. you should return all the ways/combinations in which you can "force" operations with parenthesis. I got the result (right hand side of the equation) but got stuck on the left side.  how could I have done the left side and the right hand side together? Seems like two problems in one...

```
//input:
console.log(diffWaysToCompute("2 * 3 - 4 * 5"));
//output:
(2*(3-(4*5))) = -34
((2*3)-(4*5)) = -14
((2*(3-4))*5) = -10
(2*((3-4)*5)) = -10
(((2*3)-4)*5) = 10

'use strict'

function getNumbersAndOperators(str) {
  var arr = str.split(" ");
  var operators = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] === "-" || arr[i] === "*" || arr[i] === "+") {
      operators.push(arr[i]);
      arr.splice(i, 1);
      // console.log(operators);
    }
  }
  return [arr, operators];
}
// console.log(getNumbersAndOperators("2 - 1 - 1"))
var diffWaysToCompute = function (input) {
  // var numbers = input.split(" ");
  // console.log(numbers);
  // // console.log(number);
  var results = compute(input);
  results.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a - b;
  });

  //put the numbers length into valid parenthesis:
  var NumbersAndOperators = getNumbersAndOperators(input);
  var numbers = NumbersAndOperators[0];
  console.log(numbers);
  var operators = NumbersAndOperators[1];
  console.log(operators);
  var parens = validParentheses(numbers.length);
  // console.log(numbers);
  console.log(operators);

  // for (var i = 0; i < parens.length; i++) {
  //   for (var j = 0; j < parens[i].length; j++) {
  //       var val = parens[i][j];
  //       console.log(val);
  //     if (val === " ") {
  //       var num = numbers.shift();
  //       parens.splice(val, 0, num);
  //      //starting running into infinite loops and out of time.
  //       j--;
  //     }
  //   }
  //    i--;
  // }
  console.log(parens);
  return results;
};

function validParentheses(n) {
  if (n === 1) {
    return ['( )'];
  }
  var prevParentheses = validParentheses(n - 1);
  var list = {};
  prevParentheses.forEach(function (item) {
    list['( ' + item + ' )'] = null;
    list['( )' + item] = null;
    list[item + '( )'] = null;
  });
  console.log(Object.keys(list))
  return Object.keys(list);
}

function compute(str) {
  var res = [];
  var i;
  var j;
  var k;
  var left;
  var right;
  var string = [];
  var placed = true;

  if (!/[+*-]/.test(str)) { // + - * 
    return [parseInt(str)];
  }
  for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (/\+|\-|\*/.test(str[i])) { // + - * 

      left = compute(str.substring(0, i));
      right = compute(str.substring(i + 1, str.length));
      for (j = 0; j < left.length; j++) {
        for (k = 0; k < right.length; k++) {

          if (str[i] === '+') {
            res.push(parseInt(left[j] + right[k]));
          } else if (str[i] === '-') {
            // string.push("(" + str[i-2], str[i+2] + ")");

            res.push(parseInt(left[j] - right[k]));
          } else if (str[i] === '*') {

            res.push(parseInt(left[j] * right[k]));
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }


  // console.log(string);
  return res;
}


console.log(diffWaysToCompute("2 - 1 - 1"));
console.log(diffWaysToCompute("2 * 3 - 4 * 5"));
```

Comment: Should parentheses only be added when the operators are different? e.g. should `1 + 2 + 3` produce both `(1+2)+3` and `1+(2+3)`?

Comment: no, you should return all the ways/combinations in which you can "force" operations with parenthesis.

Comment: Should `1` produce `1` or `(1)`?

Comment: I think either way is fine

Comment: Might be easier to have it with parentheses for a base case?

Comment: Just an idea, not a full answer: write it in reverse polish notation. Start with all the operators on the right and shift them toward the left one position at a time (while you can).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yikes.  That was tricky.  Good challenge.  I'm sure this could be cut way down, but it works.  I used lodash and broke the various functions down to make it more flexible.  Here's a jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mckinleymedia/3e8g22Lk/8/

Oops - had to add parseInt to the addition so it doesn't add as strings.

```
/*
//input:
diffWaysToCompute("2 * 3 - 4 * 5");

//output:
(2*(3-(4*5))) = -34 - 2,1,0
((2*3)-(4*5)) = -14 - 0,2,1 & 2,0,1
((2*(3-4))*5) = -10 - 1,0,2
(2*((3-4)*5)) = -10 - 1,2,0
(((2*3)-4)*5) =  10 - 0,1,2
*/

'use strict'
var diffWaysToCompute = function(str) {
  var opsAvailable = ['+','-','/','*'],
      numbers = [],
      operators = [],
      getNumbersAndOperators = function(str) {
          var arr = str.split(" ");
          for (var i in arr) {
              if ( opsAvailable.indexOf( arr[i] ) > -1 ) {
                  operators.push( arr[i] );
              } else {
                  numbers.push( arr[i] );
              }
          };
          return;
      },
      permutator = function(range) {
          var results = [];
          function permute(arr, memo) {
              var cur, 
                  memo = memo || [];
              for (var i in arr) {
                  cur = arr.splice(i, 1);
                  if (arr.length === 0) results.push(memo.concat(cur));
                  permute(arr.slice(), memo.concat(cur));
                  arr.splice(i, 0, cur[0]);
              }
              return results;
          }
          return permute(_.range(range));
      },
      equations = function( perms ) {
          var results = [];
          _.each(perms, function( perm, k ) {
              results[k] = nest ( perm );
          });
          return results;
      },
      nest = function( perm ) {
          var eqs = eqs || [],
              ref = ref || _.range(perm.length).map(function () { return undefined }),
              eq, 
              target = undefined;
          for (var i in perm) {
              var cur = perm[i],
                next = perm[i] + 1,
                n1 = numbers[ cur ],
                n2 = numbers[ next ],
                r1 = ref[ cur ],
                r2 = ref[ next ];
              if ( r1 !== undefined) n1 = eqs [ r1 ];
              if ( r2 !== undefined) n2 = eqs [ r2 ];
              var rNew;
              rNew = eqs.length;
              for (var x in ref ) {
                  if ( ( ref[ x ] !== undefined ) && ( ref[ x ] == r1 || ref[ x ] == r2 ) ) ref[ x ] = eqs.length;
              };
              ref[ cur ] = ref[ next ] = eqs.length;
              eqs.push({
                  ops: operators[ cur ],
                  nums: [ n1, n2 ]
              });
          };

          return eqs[ eqs.length - 1 ];
      },
      calculations = function ( eqs ) {
          var results = []
          _.each(eqs, function(equation) {
              results.push(calculate( equation ));
          });
          return results;
      },
      calculate = function( eq ) {
          var result = {
              text: ""  
          };
          // result.eq = eq;
          result.text += "( ";
          result.total = eq.nums[ 0 ];
          if ( _.isObject(result.total) ) {
              var result1 = calculate( result.total );
              result.total = result1.total;
              result.text += result1.text;
          } else {
              result.text += eq.nums[ 0 ];
          }
          _.each(eq.ops, function (op, k) {
              var num = eq.nums[ k + 1 ];
              result.text += " " + op + " ";
              if ( _.isObject(num) ) {
                  var result2 = calculate( num );
                  num = result2.total;
                  result.text += result2.text;
              } else {
                result.text += num;
              }
              if ( op === '+') result.total = parseInt(result.total) + parseInt(num);
              if ( op === '-') result.total = result.total - num;
              if ( op === '/') result.total = result.total / num;
              if ( op === '*') result.total = result.total * num;
          });
          result.text += " )";
          return result;
      },
      display = function( as ) {
          var target = document.getElementById('result');
          target.innerHTML += '<h3 class="problem">String given: ' + str + '</h3>';
          target.innerHTML += '<h4>Permutations</h4>';
          _.each( as, function(a) {
              target.innerHTML += '<div class="permutation">';
              target.innerHTML += '  <span class="formula">' + a.text + '</span> = ';
              target.innerHTML += '  <span class="total">' + a.total + '</span>';
              target.innerHTML += '</div>';
          });
      },
      perms,
      eqs,
      answers;

      getNumbersAndOperators(str);
      perms = permutator( operators.length );
      eqs = equations( perms );
      answers = calculations( eqs );
      answers = _.uniq(answers, 'text');
      display(answers);
  return answers;
};
console.log(diffWaysToCompute("2 * 3 - 4 * 5"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I never had to do such silly things, so let me try my teeth at it now.
(Caveat as always: it's highly simplified and without any checks&balances!)

The parser is the simplest thing here:

```
/*
  Use of strings instead of ASCII codes for legibility.

  I changed x - y to x + (-y) not only for convenience
  but for algebraic correctness, too.

  @param a array number nodes
  @param o array operator nodes

*/
function parse(s,a,o){
  var fnum = 0;
  var uminus = false
  for(var i=0;i<s.length;i++){
    switch(s[i]){
      case '-': uminus = true;
                a.push(fnum);
                o.push('+');
                fnum = 0;
                break;
      case '+':
      case '*':
      case '/': if(uminus){
                  uminus = false;
                  fnum *= -1;
                }
                a.push(fnum);
                o.push(s[i]);
                fnum = 0;
                break;
      case '0':
      case '1':
      case '2':
      case '3':
      case '4':
      case '5':
      case '6':
      case '7':
      case '8':
      case '9': fnum = fnum * 10 + parseInt(s[i]);
                break;
      default:  break;
    }
  }
  //assuming symmetry
  a.push(fnum);
}
```

The (-generation took me some time, too much time--I cheated here ;-)

```
/* 
   Found in an old notebook (ported from C)
   Algo. is O(n^2) and can be done faster but I
   couldn't be a...ehm, had no time, sorry.

   @idx   int    index into individual result
   @n     int    number of groups
   @open  int    number of opening parentheses
   @close int    number of closing parentheses
   @a     array  individual result
   @all   array  space for all results
*/
function makeParens(idx,n,open,close,a,all){
  if(close == n){
    all.push(a.slice(0));
    return;
  } else {
    if(open > close){
      a[idx] = ')';
      makeParens(idx+1,n,open,close+1,a,all);
    }
    if(open < n){
      a[idx] = '(';
      makeParens(idx+1,n,open+1,close,a,all);
    }
  }
}
```

And now? Yepp, that took me a while:

```
/*
   The interesting part
   Not very optimized but working

   @s string the equation
   @return array nicely formatted result
*/
function parenthesing(s){
  var nums = [];
  var ops = [];
  var all = [];
  var parens = [];

  // parse input into numbers and operators
  parse(input,nums,ops);
  /*
    Rules:

    1) out-most parentheses must be open in direction to center
       e.g.:  (1+2+3), 1+(2+3), 1+(2+3)+4
       but not: 1)+(2+3)+(4
       so: first parenthesis on the left side  must be open and
           the last parenthesis on the right side must be close

    2) parentheses in direct neighborhood to a number must be
       open in direction to the number (multiplication is
       not mutual)
       e.g.: 1+(2+3)+4, but not: 1+2(+3+4)

    3) parentheses in direct neighborhood to an operator must be
       closed in direction to the operator (multiplication is
       not mutual)
       e.g.: 1+(2+3)+4, but not: 1+2(+3+)4
  */
  // build combinations separately not in-line
  // it's already a mess, no need to add more
  makeParens(0,nums.length,0,0,[],parens);
  // You may take a look at the raw material here
  // console.log(parens.join("\n"));
  for(var i= 0;i<parens.length;i++){
    var term = [];
    // work on copies to reduce pointer juggling
    var _ops = ops.slice(0);
    var _nums = nums.slice(0);
    for(var j=0;j<parens[i].length;j++){
      if(parens[i][j] === '('){
        term.push("(");
        // rule 3
        if(parens[i][j+1] === ')'){
          term.push(_nums.shift());
        }
        // rules 1,2
        else {
          term.push(_nums.shift());
          term.push(_ops.shift());
        }
      }
      if(parens[i][j] === ')'){
        term.push(")");
        // rules 2,3
        if(parens[i][j+1] !== ')')
          term.push(_ops.shift());
      }
    }
    // some pretty printing
    term = term.join("");
    // eval() because I didn't want to write a parser
    // but if you need one...
    all.push(term + " = " + eval(term));
  }
  return all;
}
```

I'm not sure if I would get hired with *that* abomination. Ah, to be honest: I doubt it.

But I hope it is at least a little bit helpful.